# Failing to get correct file path for resource in packed Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When developing my extension and testing it by loading unpacked extension I am able to get the correct path.

For example the following code points to one of my images and loads correctly.

```
theIcon.src = chrome.runtime.getUrl(goatPath); // "chrome-extension://extensionID/img/myImage.png
```

I have the above code running in both a popup page and content script.

However when I upload to the Chrome Web Store and publish the packed version, I'm unable to access the resource because it is trying to look for it at

> chrome-extension://extensionID/chrome-extension://extensionID/img/myImage.png

Popup page error

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Content Script error

> Denying load of chrome-extension://kjohofijdcbjeanfinadbebghfegbhop/chrome-extension://kjohofijdcbjeanfinadbebghfegbhop/img/myimage.png. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

Manifest File -

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Feed the Goat",
  "description": "Feed the Goat provides a fun way for you to stay focused so you can get more done.",
  "version": "1.5",
  "icons": { "16": "img/goat-icon16.png",
             "32": "img/goat-icon32.png",
             "128": "img/goat-icon128.png" },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["event/background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/goat-icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup/authentication/authentication.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content/content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "img/goat-icon128.png",
    "img/goat-icon256.png",
    "img/GarytheGoat-icon128.png",
    "img/GarytheGoat-icon256.png",
    "img/BillyBuck-icon128.png",
    "img/BillyBuck-icon256.png",
    "img/UncleUnicorn-icon128.png",
    "img/UncleUnicorn-icon256.png"

  ],
  "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com https://use.fontawesome.com; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>",
    "identity",
    "idle",
    "notifications",
    "storage"
  ],
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What's in your manifest?

Comment: in terms of web accessible resources?

Comment: Obviously there's something wrong with the way you obtain goatPath in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest.json try to add following:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "img/*"
]
```

Also, make sure that in your dist(build) folder there is `img` folder with images.

"goatPath" should be `img/myImage.png`
and funnction should have all upper-case for `URL` like this

> chrome.runtime.getURL(goatPath)